# Answer text doesn't correspond with notification text in followed question. Expected behaviour?

Tags: support, edits, answers, notifications

In a followed question, I noticed the notification and checked [the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254243/what-is-the-point-of-giving-k-fake-memories-if-he-knows-they-are-fake-and-in-gen/254270#254270) - both after the fact by 7 minutes I noticed a discrepancy:

[image: Image of stack with flash then imprinted unexpectedly.]

**Is this expected behaviour if a question's been edited within the first 5 minutes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's within the first 5 minutes, thus it doesn't show as an edit.

It may be a bug, but for me this doesn't require any fix. Everybody read the answers by clicking on the link... Nobody reads the answer there. So IMO there is nothing wrong with this.

The inbox always just shows the first version of the post, as it was sent out. It doesn't update according to the updates of the post.

I say this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I agree, no fix necessary, just a curious quirk of the system.